# jQuery - Check if input field is untouched

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to do something with jQuery or just JavaScript (either way works). I need to check if a certain form input field is untouched AND has a value.

Essentially what's going on is that, from a previous page, a user fills out a small form... they are redirected to the full version of the form with said information pre-filled. To reduce hassle, I would like to make it so that as the user fills out the form, it skips the pre-filled input fields. I need to do this in a non-blocking away, so if a user actually clicks on a pre-filled input field to change the value, it won't just skip again.

Is this even possible?

Edit: In this context, when I say "skip", I mean as in to move onto the next form field in the form, if there is any left.

Comment: You can use "onkeydown" event on text boxes to set a variable in javascript or set a custom attribute in the textbox. On submit check that attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "skip". But you can add an event listener for the change event of the inputs and then set a class/data-attribute or store the information as a js property, so you can test for this value and treat inputs differently if they have been touched.

Comment: Updated my question with clarification. Your suggestion may work for my needs, will test and see.

Comment: So you want to focus the next empty input on the extended form page? You can just trigger `.focus()` after finding the first `input[value=""]`

Comment: The pre-filled input fields are in the middle of the form, it would eventually get to them

Comment: Ok, then you could set a tabindex value of -1 to all prefilled inputs and remove that as soon as they are changed.

Comment: That's a very elegant solution, didn't even think of that.